# Why is my pg_restore command not working?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, pg-restore, postgresql-9.6

Yesterday, I created backups of my various PostgreSQL databases using the following command:

```
pg_dump -Fc -d junk -h localhost -p 5434 -U postgres -W > z:\pg_dump\96_junk.dump
```

I created an individual backup for each database.

Today, I'm trying to restore them to an upgraded database server using the following command:

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5434 -U postgres -W -C -v z:\pg_dump\96_junk.dump
```

When I run `pg_restore` using the above it seems that the database was restored. The console screen displays a series of SQL statements and other messages I would expect to see for this database and, at the end, "PostreSQL database dump complete" is the output shown.

When I check the database, the database is not present. What am I doing wrong?

**Employed versions info**

- Backups created with version *9.6.0*
- Attempting to restore using version *9.6.1*

Comment: Try to check your `schema name` between dump and restore.

Comment: Everything is in the public schema.

Comment: Okay, it sounds good. Please show your restore log.

Comment: How do I create a restore log? I'm running the above command from a command prompt in the \bin folder of the install and the output is sent to the screen.

Comment: You can try `pg_restore -h -p.... >> restore.log`

Comment: Have you tried it after creating your db first? Eg. `createdb junk; pg_restore -d junk -U postgres z:\pg_dump\96_junk.jump`

Answer (score 7):

Try specifying the name of the DB to start in, using the `-d` or `--dbname` argument. This worked for me when I had the same problem. Note that it doesn't have to be the target DB:

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5434 -U postgres -d postgres -W -C -v z:\pg_dump\96_junk.dump
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Jen R-S said, it would work when using the "-d" option.

The output that was displaying in the console when not using the "-d" is the expected behaviour; in the documentation says:

> pg_restore can operate in two modes. If a database name is specified, pg_restore connects to that database and restores archive contents directly into the database. **Otherwise, a script containing the SQL commands necessary to rebuild the database is created and written to a file or standard output.** This script output is equivalent to the plain text output format of pg_dump.

When no database is specified, pg_restore generates all commands, you could then redirect the output to a file and then excecute the file directly.